# How to get “home screen shortcut” on iOS ipad to open in Chrome browser

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, ipad

How do you get the iPad or iPhone to have a Home Screen shortcut icon to open your website in Google Chrome and not safari?

Comment: This should be asked on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the work around I use.

1. Open callmeicons.com **using safari** (do not use another browser for this part)and click “create your own”,
2. then in the Dropdown select “website link”,
3. Next past the website URL you want to open but replace the HTTP:// with googlechromes://(YOUR URL). For example if you wanted your Home Screen shortcut icon to open https://stackoverflow.com you would enter googlechromes://stackoverflow.com
4. Next you can enter a name and then choose an icon and select “create icon” at the top menu
5. Lastly when prompted you go to the share icon (box with arrow out of the top) in safari and select “add to Home Screen”

The final result: when you click the icon added to your Home Screen it should splash Safari browser for a milli second and then realize its mistake and open your link in Google Chrome